cannot login to arch new install
I am running arch natively on an old imac and i have successfully installed arch on it. In the process, i added a root passwd and also a user id and passwd. now that i am starting up the computer and trying to log in, it wont let me by saying that the passwd is wrong and that i have 9 minutes left to unlock? the password is just 4 numbers as it is a home pc and i dont really care about the security of it as it is mostly just an experiment.
the root user and the main user id have the same passwd if that means anything.
when at the login page, the name of the user is the same as that i plugged in, so this leads me to believe the passwd should also be the same, though i did use the numpad when adding my passwd so that might be an issue.
can someone help me troubleshoot and if i cant log in, show me how to change the passwd as i cant seem to find a way to access root without logging in first
thankyou in advance for any help

To fix the password issue, since you've seemed to use the same errant password, you'll need an Arch LiveCD/USB, then youll need to mount your Filesystems, and use a chroot to make your install a new root, and lastly use the passwd command from the # prompt inside the chroot.

@eyoung100 I think this should be made into an answer.

@Vilinkameni Thanks for the tip. Comment has now been turned into an answer.

Your Issue
The OP has created an unsolvable circular dependency:

To reset the password for a user account, access to root is needed.
To reset root's password, sudo or su - can be used, but the user's passwords must be supplied.

root can also be used from a login prompt, but the same situation still exists.


The OP can guess at either password since he used the same password for both accounts, but only gets a limited number of attempts before locking the user account.

Once the user account is locked, root will be needed to unlock it .



My Hunch
The OP is using a keyboard with an integrated number pad:

While inputting what were thought to be numbers, NumLock or the Fn key was not used/pressed.
Knowing this still leaves the OP a number of unknowns while guessing, therefore the easiest fix to this problem is to use a boot disk to "reset" the password while the actual install isn't mounted.

The Fix - Tools
I'm going to assume for completeness sake that the OP does not remember the partition layout that was used when installing the system.  We will need the partition layout before we can enter the chroot to reset the passwords. Because of this we will actually need 2 USB's:

GParted Live CD/USB - This is the de-facto tool for partition management in Linux.  KDE has a similar tool, but I have yet to find someone's version of a Live boot disk based around it, and seeing that the OP cannot get to a desktop, this is our only option.
A preferred Arch Installer CD/USB - I'm going to assume that the OP still has this created due to (If this isn't true anymore, recreate the Install medium):


I am running arch natively on an old imac and i have successfully installed arch on it

The Fix - Steps

Boot the GParted Live CD, choose the proper drive, and make a note of the partition scheme for the Arch Install we are trying to fix

Copy down the partition number, and the filesystem type, for example:


sda4 is my swap partition.


sda2 is my root filesystem where / is mounted and the type is ext4.


After gathering the partition scheme, reboot, and use the Arch installer CD to gain a command prompt.

Follow the Arch Install Guide as normal up to Step 1.11, making sure to SKIP SECTION 1.9 AND 1.10. We don't want to format the existing system.  We just want to check and verify that the partitions in our installed system are still valid

Skip down to Section 3.2, as we already have a valid fstab file.  Enter the chroot per the handbook.

Check and verify Steps 3.3 - 3.6.

Reset root's password by issuing the passwd command.

Reset the daily user's password by issuing passwd myususername where myusername is your daily user.


Final Tip
As the OP learned in this experience, never use the same password for two different accounts.  Sure it's easier and you think you'll never forget but is  it really worth the hassle of the above steps if you forget?
